# Listbox form control change event

Tags: excel, listbox

I have multiselect listbox (form control, not activex) on worksheet. I need to catch event when item is being selected/deselected = listbox change event. However Listbox1_Change doesn't trigger, what should I do?

Comment: Form controls don't have events. You simply assign a macro to them.

Comment: thanks, solved like you suggested.